# Please explain to optimization of maximizing revenue.

Tags: calculus, optimization

I'm finding a hard time understanding optimization.  The equation I'm having a hard time figuring out is Maximizing revenue.

Suppose the quantity demanded per week of a certain dress to the unit price p by the demand equation $p=\sqrt{800-x}$, where p is in dollars and x is the number of dresses made. How many dresses should be made and sold each week?

I know it is $R(x)=px$.
Which I have gotten $R(x)= (800-x)^{1/2}$ which becomes $R(x)= x(800-x)^{1/2}$--> $(800x-x^2)^{1/2}$ 
The first derivative a get is $1/2(800x-x^2)^{-1/2}(800-2x)$ but then I'm stuck at this point. Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R(x) = \sqrt{800x^2 - x^3} \to R'(x) = \dfrac{1600x - 3x^2}{2\sqrt{800x^2 - x^3}} = 0 \iff 1600x - 3x^2 = 0 \iff x = 0, \frac{1600}{3}$.

Comment: how did you get the $x^3$?

Comment: $x = \sqrt{x^2}$

Comment: thank you so much. i will click the check mark once it let's me. I have to wait.